# T-SQL CTE, calculation on Previous Row value

Tags: sql-server, date, common-table-expression

I have a CTE that returns a set of rows depending on a pattern in the following way:

**Pattern Table** 
(*Create 100 rows for the next Monday starting from Start Date*)

```
|                                        |
|--Id--|--Start Date--|--Count--|--Days--|
|                                        |
|--AB--|  01-01-2000  |   100   | Monday |
|                                        |
```

And I have a *function* that calculate the next *occurring day* by passing a starting date as following:

```
dbo.fx_get_next_occurrence(@startDate DATETIME, @days VARCHAR)
```

In order to generate the rows I am using a CTE as following:

```
WITH Occurrences_CTE(Num, Id, StartDate)
AS
(
    SELECT
        SP.n
        ,F.Id
        ,dbo.fx_get_next_occurrence(F.Days, F.StartDate)
    FROM
        #RecurrencePattern AS F 
        INNER JOIN
        dbo.Numbers AS SP
        ON SP.n between 1 and F.[Count]
)
```

**dbo.numbers** is a table containing a list of incremental numbers.

Now, when I run the SELECT of course the CTE returns always the same "next date" because the Date is never increased, so this SELECT:

```
SELECT 
    CTE.Id, CTE.Num, CTE.StartDate
FROM 
    Occurrences_CTE CTE
```

Generates something like the following result:

```
|                             |
|--Id--|--Num--|--Start Date--|
|                             |
|--AB--|--001--|--01-03-2000--|
|--AB--|--002--|--01-03-2000--|
|--AB--|--003--|--01-03-2000--|
|--AB--|--004--|--01-03-2000--|
|--AB--|--005--|--01-03-2000--|
```

Now, despite the *function* which works as expected, how can I get from the CTE the *previous calculated date row* so that I can pass this date to my function to move to the next available day starting from the previous one? JOIN the CTE to itself, but then?

In am on SQL 2012 and 2014 so I can use LAG and other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a field for Every. So 1 = every week, 2 would be every other week and so on.

Take this for a spin

```
Declare @Table table (id varchar(25),StartDate Date,Count int,Days varchar(25),Every int)
Insert into @Table values
('AB','2000-01-01',50,'Monday',2),
('CD','2000-01-01',50,'Monday,Friday',2)


Declare @MinDate Date = (Select min(StartDate) from @Table)
Declare @MaxCntr Int  = (Select max(Count) from @Table)
Declare @MaxDate Date = DateAdd(wk,@MaxCntr+10,@MinDate)

;With cteKeyDate As (
    Select KeyDate = @MinDate,KeyDOW = DateName(WEEKDAY,@MinDate),KeyWeek = datepart(WK,@MinDate)
    Union All
    Select KeyDate =  DateAdd(DD, 1, df.KeyDate) ,KeyDOW = DateName(WEEKDAY,DateAdd(DD, 1, df.KeyDate)), KeyWeek= DatePart(WK,DateAdd(DD, 1, df.KeyDate))
    From cteKeyDate DF
    Where DF.KeyDate <= @MaxDate
) 
Select * 
 From (
        Select A.ID
              ,A.StartDate
              ,A.Count
              ,A.Days 
              ,A.Every
              ,KeyDate
              ,KeyDow
              ,KeyWeek
              ,RowNr = Row_Number() over (Partition By A.ID Order By B.KeyDate)
         from @Table A
         Join cteKeyDate B on B.KeyDate>=A.StartDate and Charindex(KeyDOW,Days)>0 
      ) Final
 Where RowNr<=Count and (KeyWeek) % (Every) = 0 
 Option (maxrecursion 32767)
```

Comment: It works like a charm plus today you teach me how to seriously iterate with DATEADD without using a LOOKUP calendar.
Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could simplify this a bit.

I can't speak to your UDF, but it may not be necessary as you may soon see.  The cteKeyDate produces more than necessary, but the results are filtered when you join to your data.

You may also notice that I added another row to your sample data which occurs on Monday's and Fridays, but for a count of only 50

```
Declare @Table table (id varchar(25),StartDate Date,Count int,Days varchar(25))
Insert into @Table values
('AB','2000-01-01',100,'Monday'),
('CD','2000-01-01',50,'Monday,Friday')


Declare @MinDate Date = (Select min(StartDate) from @Table)
Declare @MaxCntr Int  = (Select max(Count) from @Table)
Declare @MaxDate Date = DateAdd(wk,@MaxCntr+10,@MinDate)

;With cteKeyDate As (
    Select KeyDate = @MinDate,KeyDOW = DateName(WEEKDAY,@MinDate)
    Union All
    Select KeyDate =  DateAdd(DD, 1, df.KeyDate) ,KeyDOW = DateName(WEEKDAY,DateAdd(DD, 1, df.KeyDate))
    From cteKeyDate DF
    Where DF.KeyDate <= @MaxDate
) 
Select * 
 From (
        Select A.ID
              ,A.StartDate
              ,A.Count
              ,A.Days 
              ,KeyDate
              ,KeyDow
              ,RowNr = Row_Number() over (Partition By A.ID Order By B.KeyDate)
         from @Table A
         Join cteKeyDate B on B.KeyDate>=A.StartDate and Charindex(KeyDOW,Days)>0 
      ) Final
 Where RowNr<=Count
 Option (maxrecursion 32767)
```

Returns -- I showed all fields so you can better visualize the results

```
ID  StartDate   Count   Days            KeyDate     KeyDow  RowNr
AB  2000-01-01  100     Monday          2000-01-03  Monday  1
AB  2000-01-01  100     Monday          2000-01-10  Monday  2
AB  2000-01-01  100     Monday          2000-01-17  Monday  3
AB  2000-01-01  100     Monday          2000-01-24  Monday  4
... 
AB  2000-01-01  100     Monday          2001-11-05  Monday  97
AB  2000-01-01  100     Monday          2001-11-12  Monday  98
AB  2000-01-01  100     Monday          2001-11-19  Monday  99
AB  2000-01-01  100     Monday          2001-11-26  Monday  100
CD  2000-01-01  50      Monday,Friday   2000-01-03  Monday  1
CD  2000-01-01  50      Monday,Friday   2000-01-07  Friday  2
CD  2000-01-01  50      Monday,Friday   2000-01-10  Monday  3
.....
CD  2000-01-01  50      Monday,Friday   2000-06-16  Friday  48
CD  2000-01-01  50      Monday,Friday   2000-06-19  Monday  49
CD  2000-01-01  50      Monday,Friday   2000-06-23  Friday  50
```

Comment: Wow, you really twisted the logic. I just run your query with Execution Plan and it's working very well. Thank you!

Comment: One more question, what if I have an extra column that specifies the number of weeks I have to skip? Your script would work when I have to count _n_ days every consecutive week, what if I want to accomplish the same on "every 3 weeks"? Because the CTE does not get params from the Table

Comment: Added another answer to support SKIPS see comment

Comment: Sorry @John Cappelletti I can't see it with the skip

Comment: I removed it because I wasn't happy with the logic

Comment: Ok, I think the point is that the CTE should somehow be aware of the "skip" column in order to run the correct DateAdd or the CTE should join the table which contains the pattern

Comment: Nope.  You'll see.  Just validating the results